# Sketchup run script in background

Tags: ruby, scripting, sketchup

I am trying to create a Sketchup script that emulates the native autosave functionality of OS X, by saving whenever possible. However, I can't seem to run the script without it causing Sketchup to stop responding (for obvious reasons). How can I get it to run in the background, e.g. on another thread?

```
loop {
    sleep(1)
    model = Sketchup.active_model
    model.save()
}
```

Comment: But Sketchup already [supports autosave](http://help.sketchup.com/en/article/36212)

Comment: Not automatic saving-in-place. The result is that every time I log out of my computer after working with Sketchup, it asks me to save my file.

Answer (score 1):

`sleep` is a blocking function - nothing else is allowed to run because the Ruby interpreter runs in the main thread. And the SketchUp API can only be called from the main thread.

Instead you can use a timer:

```
interval = 60 * 5 # 5 minutes
timer_id = UI.start_timer(interval, true) {
  model = Sketchup.active_model
  model.save() if model # OSX might have no models open
}
```

If you want to stop the timer:
`UI.stop_timer(timer_id)`